# VBA: Add single value to single column array

Tags: excel, vba

1. I do not know the size of the array.
2. The array is created from a column L on sheet "INPUT_MASTERDATA".

This is what I have so far:

```
With Worksheets("INPUT_MASTERDATA")
    arrInputUniqueItems = .Range("L2", .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```

I would like to include the value "x" in the above array.

*Sample data from Range L on Worksheet "INPUT_MASTERDATA"*

```
R83711850
1210221340
1210223342
R83711181
R83711931
```

These all goes into the array just fine. Now I would like to add the value "x". So the array afterwards looks like this:

```
R83711850
1210221340
1210223342
R83711181
R83711931
x
```

Any ideas or help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be dynamically adding items to your collection you should consider a better suitable data type like `Collection`. Array's are not supposed by resized after their dimensions are specified.

So... consider creating an array from range in one go, then loading that into a `Collection` and then you can add more items to the collection. The reason you want to use the array is to load the entire range into memory is going to be faster than iterating a Range and adding each cell to the collection directly.

```
Sub Main()

    [L1] = "header"
    [L2] = "R83711850"
    [L3] = "1210221340"
    [L4] = "1210223342"
    [L5] = "R83711181"
    [L6] = "R83711931"

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim v As Variant
    Dim c As New Collection

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Range("L2:L" & lastRow).Value

    For Each v In arr
        c.Add v
    Next

    ' then if you ever need to add more just add it to the collection
    c.Add "new value"

    ' print to confirm
    For Each v In c
        Debug.Print v
    Next

End Sub
```

prints

```
R83711850
 1210221340 
 1210223342 
R83711181
R83711931
new value
```

in the Immediate Window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot though I get a runtime error 13. I was trying to follow this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739510/excel-vba-compare-two-ranges-and-find-non-matches. But I want to add the value x to the collection so that these rows will not be removed. Any idea on that? I think my error has to do with the use of cstr

Comment: I believe this answer answers your original question. If you have a new question please consider asking a new one with your current code as modifying this question would invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily enough without resorting to further loops and/or other methods.

1. Simply use a range 1 cell longer than the end of the range of interest, or
2. Use `ReDim` on a 1D array (of course you can and should resize arrays)

*code 1*

```
Sub Method1_2D()
Dim arrInputUniqueItems
With Worksheets("INPUT_MASTERDATA")
    arrInputUniqueItems = .Range("L2", .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    arrInputUniqueItems(UBound(arrInputUniqueItems), 1) = "X"
End With
End Sub
```

*code 2*

```
Sub Method2_1D()
Dim arrInputUniqueItems
With Worksheets("INPUT_MASTERDATA")
    arrInputUniqueItems = Application.Transpose(.Range("L2", .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))
    ReDim Preserve arrInputUniqueItems(UBound(arrInputUniqueItems))
    arrInputUniqueItems(UBound(arrInputUniqueItems)) = "X"
End With
End Sub
```